# How to create and use onclick functions in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, ejs

I am trying to make a trivia game. I want to make it where you can click on an answer and that creates a border and increments the points variable

Here is the the whole page.

```
    <% include ../partials/boilerplate %>

<%  var points = 0; 
correctAnswer = (num) =>  {     
    document.getElementById(`correctAnswer${i}`).style.border = "5px solid black";
    points+=1
 } %>


<div class="triviaContainer">
    <h1>WELCOME TO TOP FACT </h1>
    <% var i =0; data.forEach(question =>{  %>
<div class="questionRow">
    <div> <%= question.question %></div>
</div>
<div class="questionRow1">
    <div class="correctAnswer<%= i+=1 %>" onclick=  <%= correctAnswer(i) %>  > A: <%= question.correct_answer %></div>
    <div>B: <%= question.incorrect_answers[0].incorrect_answer %></div>
</div>
<div class="questionRow2">
    <div>C: <%= question.incorrect_answers[1].incorrect_answer %></div>
    <div>D: <%= question.incorrect_answers[2].incorrect_answer %></div>
</div>


 <%   }) %>
   </div>
```

I want to be able to use this function onclick entering a parameter of what question it is since the questions are being generated in a loop as shown above.

```
<%  var points = 0; 
correctAnswer = (num) =>  {     
    document.getElementById(`correctAnswer${i}`).style.border = "5px solid black";
    points+=1
 } %>
```

The inline onclick code is listed below.

```
 <div class="correctAnswer<%= i+=1 %>" onclick=  <%= correctAnswer(i) %>  > A: 
<%= question.correct_answer %></div>
```

I keep getting this error in ejs

```
    ReferenceError: /Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/views/trivia/trivia-index.ejs:17
    15|     </div>
    16|     <div class="questionRow1">
 >> 17|         <div class="correctAnswer<%= i+=1 %>" onclick=  <%= correctAnswer(i) %>  > A: <%= question.correct_answer %></div>
    18|         <div>B: <%= question.incorrect_answers[0].incorrect_answer %></div>
    19|     </div>
    20|     <div class="questionRow2">

document is not defined
    at correctAnswer (eval at compile (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:24:9)
    at data.forEach.question (eval at compile (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:38:26)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at returnedFn (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/jdiperi88/wdi/UNIT_02/projects/trivia/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
```

What would be the best way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

EJS just puts together the view with the help of javascript on server side and renders it (sends to the browser). Beyond that it has no function. What you are trying to achieve is what javascript in `<script>` tag should do on client side.

Something like this (untested):

```
<script>
var points = 0; 
function correctAnswer(num){     
    document.getElementById(correctAnswer' + num).style.border = "5px solid black";
    points+=1;
}
</script>
```